# When does Python do automatic type conversion?

Tags: python

When does Python do automatic type conversion?

--

Update:

I asked this after reading this post: [In praise of Go or : "Why I moved from Python and C++ to Go"](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/7a980dfc568a54f2#). The one of the points the poster makes is that:

> - It is statically typed, so it is more explicit and the code of a third
>     party is more readable. Also it
>     eliminates the risk of unwanted
>     automatic type conversions (unlike
>     Python).

I had no idea what he meant by "unwanted automatic type conversions". Now, I think he's talking about [implicit numeric conversions](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#conversions). Of course, Python has these as `1.0 + 2` will convert `2` to `2.0` and return `3.0`.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic type conversion"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't - it has [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) instead.

(I may have misunderstood what you meant by automatic type conversion, though, so it would help if you give more detail in your question.)